# In hp-UFT using VB Script can you name an IE browser window in VB Script so that you can control which window does the navigation?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I understand how to open new IE browsers and tabs but is there a way to say:

this is browser1

this is browser2

browser2.navigate(aol.com)

browser1.navigate(stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers in UFT can be identified using any unique properties, but these properties can change with the change in the URL you are opening, So there are actually two independent properties which you can use to identify the browsers

1) Creation time : This is the when the browser is created so, for the first browser its 0, second its 1 and third its 2.

2) hwnd : its the windows handle for the browser, its the number using which windows OS identifies the objects it creates.

So now with this understanding, in UFT you can create the browser object for multiple browsers

1) Simply create the browser objects.
2) To create browser objects

```
Set Browser1 = Browser("CreationTime:=0")
set Browser2 = Browser("CreationTime:=1")
.
.
.
.
.
.
set Browsern = Browser("CreationTime:=n-1")
```

You can also use hwnd, but its will not be as easy as creation time.

now,we can also use the CreateObject for creating the object of IE, but below are the disadvantages to doing so

1) CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") can be used with latest version of IE for the older versions its CreateObject("Internet.Application") for future versions it could be something else.

2) You will loose the ability to work with in built UFT functions, because when you use createobject then only functions exposed by browser api's will be visible(in UFT's terminology Native functions and properties). What this means is

You cant write the below code, if you use the createobject function to create the browser object

Browser1.Sync

You will have to use an unreliable loop on Readystate property.

Comment: CreationTime seems to be the easiest and most consistent way to make this work! Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your pseudo code.

```
set IE1= CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE1.Visible = True
IE1.Navigate URL1

set IE2= CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE2.Visible = True
IE2.Navigate URL2
```

https://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/Command-to-launch-browser-and-go-to-a-URL-in-QTP/td-p/4223362

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browser's [`OpenURL` property](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Web/Web_Browser_Properties.htm%3FTocPath%3DObject%2520Model%2520Reference%2520for%2520GUI%2520Testing%7CWeb%7CBrowser%2520Object%7C_____1), this property is set at the creation of the browser and is consistent for its entire lifetime.

First launch the browser to a specific URL (this can be used just to identify the browser) and then navigate away to the real part of the test. I see that http://example.com ignores URL parameters so you can use that.

E.g.

```
SystemUtil.Run "Chrome.exe", "example.com/?first"     
SystemUtil.Run "Chrome.exe", "example.com/?second"

Browser("OpenUrl:=.*first").Navigate "zombo.com"
Browser("OpenUrl:=.*second").Navigate "stackoverflow.com/users/3848"
```